# SwipeRefreshLayout остановить событие по нажатию на экран

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

Всем привет.
Подскажите пожалуйста реализацию такого поведения.
В общем у меня есть layout,  в котором содержится компонент RecyclerView обернутый в SwipeRefreshLayout.

**Вот код layout'a:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.astar.myled.view.ui.main.MainViewModel" />

        <variable
            name="adapter"
            type="com.astar.myled.view.adapter.LampAdapter" />
    </data>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/scanRefreshLayout"
        app:swipeRefreshLayoutProgressSpinnerBackgroundColor="@color/colorGray3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/root_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorGray0">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_lamp_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="4dp"
                app:adapter="@{adapter}"
                app:adapterLampList="@{viewModel.lampListLiveData}"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:toast="@{viewModel.toastLiveData}"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_lamp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</layout>
```

Когда я свайпаю вниз я хочу запустить какое то действие, и по нажатию на экран остановить это действие. Для этого я использую OnTouchListener. Я его вешаю на RecyclerView, но при этом у меня полностью блокируется прокрутка в RecyclerView.

**Код фрагмента:**

```
class LampFragment : DatabindingFragment(), SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, View.OnTouchListener {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentLampBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = binding<FragmentLampBinding>(inflater, R.layout.fragment_lamp, container).apply {
            viewModel = getViewModel<MainViewModel>().apply { fetchLampList() }
            lifecycleOwner = this@LampFragment
            adapter = LampAdapter()

            scanRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorGray3, R.color.colorGray2, R.color.colorGray1, R.color.colorGray4)
            scanRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this@LampFragment)
            recyclerLampList.setOnTouchListener(this@LampFragment)
        }
        return binding.root
    }


    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            stopScan()
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onRefresh() {
        Intent(activity, TestService::class.java).also {
            activity?.bindService(it, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }
    }

    private val mConnection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName?) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Сервис разъединен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show()
        }

        override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder?) {
            Snackbar.make(binding.rootContainer, "Lamp scanning...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    private fun stopScan() {
        if (scanRefreshLayout.isRefreshing) {
            scanRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
            activity?.unbindService(mConnection)
            Snackbar.make(binding.rootContainer, "Stop scanning.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Не очень понимаю как быть в таком случае. Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо вот в этом методе

```
 override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean
```

вернуть `false`, тогда ваш клик будет так же обрабатывать `View` которая находится под `View` которая обрабатывает `onTouch()`